# Is there a numpy biginteger?

Tags: python, numpy, biginteger

Hmm. There doesn't seem to me a way to store Python's bigintegers in a numpy array. Is there something special you have to do, to declare a numpy array with bigints?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Not specifically, no.  You can create an array with `dtype='object'`, which creates an array of Python objects (including but not limited to ints).  This will get you a lot of Numpy array-like functionality but few to none of the performance benefits.

Which is to say, an array of Python objects is not significantly different from a Python `list` in terms of memory performance.  Though if you must use bigints it may still be preferable to using a `list` since you still get element-wise arithmetic operations, including when doing operations with other Numpy arrays.  For example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: big = np.array([10**100, 10**101, 10**102], dtype='object')

In [3]: big
Out[3]: 
array([ 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
       100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
       1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000], dtype=object)

In [4]: big + np.array([1, 2, 3])
Out[4]: 
array([ 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001,
       100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002,
       1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003], dtype=object)
```

I've never used this capability myself though, so I'm not entirely sure what other surprising limitations might arise.

Comment: Seems to work fine. I played with computing Fibonacci numbers using `numpy` matrices populated with ints and everything works, including operations like `dot` and `matrix_power`.

Comment: Incidentally, I've been thinking of adding a GMP-based big integer type to Numpy. I haven't had significant enough personal motivation to do it but I think it could be useful.