# fibonacci sequence negative answer after 92 python

Tags: python, numpy, fibonacci

I am trying to create a function that gives me the fibonacci sequence for any value of n. However, after the n = 92, I am getting incorrect answers.

```
eg. For n = 93
Expected output = 12200160415121876738
Actual Output = -6246583658587674878
```

My code is below:

```
import numpy as np
def Power(M, n):
         if not n:
                 return 1
         elif n % 2:
                 return M*Power(M, n-1)
         else:
                 sqrt = Power(M, n//2)
                 return sqrt**2

  def _fib(n):
     G = np.matrix([[1,1],[1,0]])
     F = Power(G, n)
     return F[0,1]
```

I think it has something to do with integer overflow related to the limitation of the matrix library. I am not sure how to fix it. Please help me out. I would prefer if this algorithm is improved upon.

Algorithm used:
[image]

Comment: What is the algorithm you're using here?

Comment: @AKX added the algorithm in the question

Comment: Have you tried setting an explicit `dtype` for the matrix? BTW, getting `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable` instead...

Comment: I am not getting any type of this error like the Type Error . I have not tried to do dtype - how to do that?

Comment: 32-bit Integer overflow: `2^31 + 6246583658587674878 = 12200160415121876738`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should allow big-int numbers, otherwise you are limited with the default 63 bits (+sign bit) or with `np.uint64` which is only 1 bit larger:

```
import numpy as np
def Power(M, n):
   if not n:
      # Original 'return 1' does not work with n=0
      return np.identity(2, dtype=object)
   elif n % 2:
      return M*Power(M, n-1)
   else:
      sqrt = Power(M, n//2)
      return sqrt**2

def fib(n):
     # This allows for big-int
     G = np.matrix([[1,1],[1,0]], dtype=object)
     F = Power(G, n)
     return F[0,1]
```

Comment: Thank u! This works for any value for n. Can you just describe what does dtype=object means? just turning int into Bigint?

Comment: @UtsoRoy read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28552599/is-there-a-numpy-biginteger

Answer (score 3):

You should set an explicit `dtype` to allow for larger numbers in your matrix:

```
G = np.matrix([[1,1],[1,0]], dtype=np.uint64)
```

However, this raises the bar only slightly (if your system is not even using this as a default) and will soon overflow, too, and you won't even notice it as easily as the numbers will not get negative...

[@Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54980117/1639625) works much better.

Comment: Thank u! Just a clarification - does this increase it from 32 bit to 64 bit for the integer?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there a way to increase the limit? I want to make a graph till n=15,000

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're bumping into floating point precision issues.

Python 3's integers are arbitrary precision, so you can just use them and `lru_cache` for memoization:

```py
from functools import lru_cache


@lru_cache()
def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    return fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1)


for x in range(1, 95):
    print(x, fib(x - 1))
```

outputs

```
1 1
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 5
6 8
7 13
8 21
9 34
10 55
11 89
12 144
13 233
14 377
15 610
16 987
...
92 7540113804746346429
93 12200160415121876738
94 19740274219868223167
```

Comment: I would prefer if my current algorithm is fixed upon - I have added it in the edit.

Comment: The OP algorithm takes O(log N) of basic operations and uses O(1) objects, while memoization is O(N) of basic operations and uses O(N) objects for the first call to fib(N). Actually, since these are big-int the complexity is O((log N)**2) vs. O(N log N).