# Does numpy not have arbitrary integer precision like Python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, precision

While trying to solve a problem, I came across the following limitation: `numpy` doesn't seem to have arbitrary integer precision!

Here is what I did:

```py
import numpy as np

data = list(range(1, 21))

# ------- Regular Python --------
prod = 1
for el in data:
    prod*=el
print(prod)

# ------- NumPy --------
parr = np.prod(np.array(data, np.int64))
print(parr)
```

The results obtained are as follows:

```bash
2432902008176640000
2432902008176640000
```

So far, so good. Now, if we increase upper limit of the `range` from `21` to just `22`, we can observe the limitation; the results will now be:

```bash
51090942171709440000
-4249290049419214848
```

My questions are

1. why doesn't NumPy inherit the arbitrary integer precision from Python?
2. why do we have this limitation? (*or, am I making some mistake?*)
3. how to overcome it?

---

**Update**

The [possible duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28552630/14739759) suggests using a `dtype=object`, but, that takes away all numpy performance benefits for numeric data!

Comment: @mkrieger1 If I make a numpy array of object dtype, for integers, then it beats the purpose of using numpy (_as per the solution at the link you have suggested_)

Comment: Yes. But NumPy doesn't have an unlimited size integer type. If you want the NumPy performance you have to use the available types.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I figured as much, but, that is what confuses me - why can't numpy simply use the method Python handles it? I mean, I wish to understand the internal workings

Comment: AFAIK, numpy uses C backend for vectorization and acceleration. One thing about C acceleration is that one can perform arithmetic operations on larger memory block (128bits or so) using chip-specific instruction (e.g. SSE). That's where you need to know the specific memory layout, which pretty much dictates the `dtype` memory size. TLDR: it's would be difficult to write accelerated operators for arbitrary large integers

Comment: well, I guess the current solution is to use the `dtype=object` method. I guess we can close this question as a duplicate, then. Thanks and sorry

Comment: *Of course* `numpy` doesn't have arbitrary precision integers. The *whole point* of numpy is to use fixed-size arrays of primitive, numeric types *for their speed advantage* over Python objects. How did you expect `numpy` to have advantages over Python otherwise? You ask, "why can't numpy simply use the method Python handles it?" well, because *then it wouldn't be fast*, which is the whole point